# My goal is to produce 2 functions that use while loops to:

Tags: c

a.) (function 1) take user input and decrement the value until userNum = zero

b.) (function 2) take the original user input and have zero increase by +1 until reaching said user input.

therefore, the output would look like this:

Please enter a positive integer: 5         (**enters 5**)

5

4

3

2

1

0

(four asterisks)

0

1

2

3

4

5

My problem is, I cant figure out how to set the original input for userNum in place so I can all it in the "loop_up_to_int" function. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int loop_down_to_zero(void);
int loop_up_to_int(void);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   int userNum;

   printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &userNum);
   //printf("%d\n", userNum);

   loop_down_to_zero();
   loop_up_to_int();

 return 0;  
}

//definitions here
int loop_down_to_zero() {

   //scanf("%d", &userNum);  do i scan for input here?
      while (userNum >= 0) {
         printf("%d\n", userNum);
         userNum = userNum - 1;
      }
   printf("****\n");
}

int loop_up_to_int() {

   int newNum;
   int userNum;

   newNum = 0;
   printf("%d\n", newNum);
      while (newNum != userNum)
      {
         newNum = newNum + 1;
         printf("%d\n", newNum);
      }
}
```

error message:

daily08.c:58:14: error: 'userNum' undeclared (first use in this function)
       while (userNum >= 0) {

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do that would be to store userNum's value in another variable and then set userNum back to the original value between loop_down_to_zero() and loop_up_to_int()

Comment: This doesn't look like c++, why did you tag it that way?

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is because userNum doesn't exist in the function. It's only declared in main. Passing values is the solution.

You can pass values into functions (a core idea behind programming; variables shouldn't be global).  Similar to how main has int in it's declaration; update both your functions to take a variable:

```
 int loop_down_to_zero(int number)
```

Don't forget to update the function definition on top of your program also.

And you call the function by simply saying `loop_down_to_zero(userNum)`. What you entered can now be accessed via number in each function, and userNum will stay intact in main().

---

Side note: When functions are done, they can return a value back to the caller. In your case you don't do that (nor do you need to).  Both your functions should show they don't return anything, which is marked by using void i.e. `void loop_down_to_zero(int number)`. Again remember to update the top of your program also.

Comment: so the new variable "number" should be set equal to the original input? How would I be able to carry it into a function if its declared in main? Adding it as an argument prompts the "too many arguments" error.

Comment: Update all your functions, as well as defintion on top as described. You don't declare number as a new variable.  Simply add userNum to the parentesis (inside of main). In the functions you refer to number instead of userNum. Nobody besides main should mention userNum.